# How to declare an INTEGER_64 from number?

Tags: eiffel

How to declare an INTEGER_64 from a declared number?

`("3000000000").to_integer_64`

is the only way I found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
{INTEGER_64} 3000000000
```

examples:

```
local
    int_64: INTEGER_64
do
    int_64 := {INTEGER_64} 3000000000
    do_something_with_an_int_64 ({INTEGER_64} 3000000000)
end
```

The same applies to all variants of `INTEGER`, `NATURAL`, `REAL`, `STRING` and (since EiffelStudio 19.07) `IMMUTABLE_STRING`.